# How is $ \cos (\alpha / \beta) $ expressed in terms of $\cos \alpha $ and $ \cos \beta $?

Tags: trigonometry

If it is possible to express  $ \cos n \alpha $ in terms of $ \cos \alpha $  as a power series for integer $n$ ...

I like to see an expression for the quotient angle that obviously tallies when $ (\alpha , \beta) $ are swapped.

EDIT1:

Something like:

$$ \cos (\alpha - \beta)= \cos \alpha \cos \beta  + \sin \alpha  \sin \beta $$

EDIT2:

Like to know why $ \cos ( \alpha / \beta )$ cannot be expressed in terms of $ \cos \alpha, \cos \beta $, but  $ \cos ( \alpha + \beta) $  can be expressed in terms of  $\cos \alpha $ and $ \cos \beta. $

Comment: Are you able to express $\cos\frac{\alpha}{\pi}$ in terms of $\cos(\alpha)$?

Comment: You can take the power series for $\cos x$ and just plug in $n\alpha$ for $x$.

Comment: No, it is possible for integral $n$. I mention it only as it occurs to anyone at the beginning during approach..shall edit it.

Comment: @Narasimham I think you might want to rewrite the question, because right now it makes no sense.

Comment: I haven't looked it up but if that's a correct use of the word "tally" I've never heard of it.

Comment: @Braindead Thanks. Right now  responses are on.I am open to changing it on indications making more sense.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by "tally", but if you're referring, as per your example, to the fact that $\cos(\alpha-\beta)=\cos(\beta-\alpha)$, it is not the case that $\cos(\alpha/\beta)=\cos(\beta/\alpha)$.

Comment: @Narasimham What is "$\beta$" for $\cos(n\alpha)$?

Comment: @Braindead $ \beta = 1/n $

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\cos(\alpha)$ and $\cos(\beta)$ are periodic functions.

Now assume that $\cos(\alpha\beta)=f(\cos(\alpha),\cos(\beta))$ and set $\alpha=\beta=x$. Then $\cos(x^2)=f(\cos(x),\cos(x))$ must be a periodic function, which is obviously false. So such a formula cannot exist.

Similar reasoning with $\cos((x+1)/x)$ excludes a formula for division.

This contrast with the case of addition, for which  "$\cos(2x)$ must be periodic" raises no contradiction.

Comment: Indeed so.. .but I was asking about quotient argument in particular. For x=y,  $ \cos (x/y) = \cos( 1 radian) = f( \cos(x) ) $, many values f can be found for it, Right ?  $

Comment: I answered for the quotient. The case $\alpha=\beta=x$ is uninformative.

Answer (score 4):

$\cos(n\alpha)$ is indeed expressible as a polynomial in terms of $\cos(\alpha)$ (and $\sin(\alpha)$). Reciprocally, you can in some cases solve that polynomial to obtain $\cos(\alpha/n)$ in terms of $\cos(\alpha)$.

But there is nothing like formulas expressing $\cos(\alpha\beta)$ or $\cos(\alpha/\beta)$ in terms of $\cos(\alpha)$ and $\cos(\beta)$.

Just like $e^{\alpha\beta}$ and $e^{\alpha/\beta}$ are not expressible in terms of $e^\alpha$ and $e^\beta$.

Comment: I know it.  just want to know why $ \cos ( \alpha / \beta )$ cannot be expressed in terms of $ \cos \alpha, \cos \beta $, but  $ \cos ( \alpha + \beta) $  can be expressed in terms of  $\cos \alpha $ and $ \cos \beta. $